# In app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchases, android, java

Делаю In app purchase по этой [инструкции](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Android_Studio_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_Tutorial).

При установке на смартфон и запуске покупки в дайлере, где он должен отображать информацию о покупке и цену, то есть самая первая страница, там написано "Вам необходимо войти в аккаунт Google". Запускаю на физическом телефоне, где вход в аккаунт уже сделан. В чем может быть дело?

[Вот мой код в гите](https://github.com/Eldqs/inapppurchase2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно собрать релиз версию с подписью через ваш ключ и все должно заработать.

Comment: @deadkenny нет, не работает. такая же ошибка

Comment: как в итоге решили проблему? Я делаю так же, и подписываю приложение, но почему то пишет ту же проблему - Необходимо войти в аккаунт Google. ничего не понятно.

Comment: @inkognitum А вы вошли в аккаунт гугл на устройстве? Проверьте лучше правильно ли вы указываете название продукта, который хотите купить.

Answer (score 2):

В консоли разработчика нужно активировать товар для продажи (у меня так было, когда забыл активировать)